# Use a different image if Dark Mode is enabled on Android

Tags: android, android-dark-theme

I have two variants of a PNG, one where the drawn text is black and one where it is white. By default, on a white background, I am using the black image variant, but when the system dark mode is enabled the image becomes nearly invisible against the background.

**How can I instruct my app to use the alternate image when dark mode is enabled?**

The image is set in the activity's XML:

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.me.some_app.someActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/Logo"
        android:layout_width="176dp"
        android:layout_height="219dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/LogoDescription"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/divider"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo_black" />
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I solved this with the following process:

1. Create a new directory at `app/src/main/res/drawable-night`, mimicking the already existing path at `app/src/main/res/drawable`.
2. Move the white variant image into the new `drawable-night` directory, changing the name from `logo_white.png` to `logo.png`.
3. Rename the black variant image in the standard `drawable` directory from `logo_black.png` to `logo.png`
4. Update the `ImageView` drawable reference from `@drawable/logo_black` to `@drawable/logo`

It appears that Android recognizes the night variant directory and flips accordingly. *Very nice :)*

Comment: Does it be applied also to SVG icons?....

Answer (score 32):

You can use the following steps:

1). Go to Resource Manager from **Left Side Bar** or **View > Tool Windows > Resource Manager**
[image]

2). Select Drawable Tab ( If not selected )
[image]

3). Click *"+"* icon and select **Import Drawables**
[image]

4). Select the files and click **OK**.
[image]

5). Rename both files to same name. *baseline_feedback_20* in my case ( Ignore the warning for now )
[image]

6). Click **Add another qualifier**, select **Night Mode** with value **Day Time** for Light mode and **Night Time** for Dark Mode.

You can read about Qualifiers more [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources).
[image]

7). Click **Next** then **Import** and you are done.

You can use the resources as usual `@drawable/logo` or `@drawable/baseline_feedback_20` in my case and the system will fetch the file as per the selected mode.

Answer (score 2):

I have simple solution for it, and you need only a set of images, the color doesn't matter, on the component you'll use the image set the following attribute:

android:tint="@color/you_desired_color" or app:tint="@color/you_desired_color" depends of component.

For example

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        app:tint="@color/you_desired_color" />
```

In res folder you need to have the following folders
values and values-night, each of them with its respective themes.xml and colors.xml