# Images change colour when i switch to dark mode in apps

Tags: java, android, imageview, darkmode

My Images inside a ImageView change their color from to white when I turn on my Dark Mode.

I am putting some croppe screen shots of the images so you can understand better.

**What my Images need to like(In Light Mode):**
[image]

**What my image look like in dark mode**

[image]

The black color of the Image turned into white, and white into black when I turned ON dark mode.What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [setForceDarkAllowed(false)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setForceDarkAllowed(boolean)) if you don't want this View to invert colors when dark mode is enabled.

Alternatively, you can [use a different set of images for dark mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64924236/4179315).

Comment: Thanks mate.I used android:forceDarkAllowed=false . And it worked.

Comment: I'm glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

I used android:forceDarkAllowed=false in the ImageView. And it worked.